# Correct project build settings for project deployment using box.com Box.V2 C# SDK

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64, box-api

I'm building a desktop application for Windows 7 using the Box.V2 SDK referenced below.  I have no problems executing the application on the build machine.  However, it won't run on the machines I deploy it to.  I've tried to deploy to a Windows 7 64-bit virtual machine on my box as well as a separate machine with Windows 7 64-bit installed.

Box.com C# SDK - https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2

The program crashes and I'm getting the follow error output:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: testboxinstall.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 52553750
  Problem Signature 04: Box.V2
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 51df6f91
  Problem Signature 07: d
  Problem Signature 08: 0
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I have my project set to copy references and I'm including those dll's in the deployment folder.  I suspect my problem still lies in some missing or incorrect references, but I'm having quite a bit of trouble tracking down the issue.  I've used Dependency Walker to try and figure it out and it does point out some x86/x64 differences in the libraries but even knowing that, I still can't seem to fix it.

With all that said, can anyone tell me what the proper build settings are?  What platform should I target?  What framework?  Could there be libraries that I'm missing?  Would anyone be able to provide further help for troubleshooting?  Any help would be appreciated.

Some more information about my project that might be relevant:

I've used nuget to install the Box.V2 package.
I've ALSO tried downloading the Box.V2 source and built it as a 64-bit library.

I created a simple form application in an effort to get it working.  I believe the details aren't relevant, but I've included it below anyway.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Box.V2;
using Box.V2.Config;

namespace TestBoxInstall
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            BoxClient client = new BoxClient( new BoxConfig( "secret", "key" , new Uri("http://go.to.here.com") ));
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is my project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{EDDF2D18-1DE7-46A5-8206-201430898D58}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>TestBoxInstall</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>TestBoxInstall</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>
    </TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\outputs\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>6AD4046A78A42DE3E2986DAB5763329844F79313</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestKeyFile>TestBoxInstall_TemporaryKey.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignManifests>true</SignManifests>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Box.V2">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Box.V2.1.0.2\lib\portable-net40+sl40+wp71+win\Box.V2.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.16\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.16\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Async.1.0.16\lib\net40\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Nito.AsyncEx">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Nito.AsyncEx.1.0.0\lib\net40\Nito.AsyncEx.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Nito.AsyncEx.Concurrent">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Nito.AsyncEx.1.0.0\lib\net40\Nito.AsyncEx.Concurrent.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Nito.AsyncEx.Enlightenment">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Nito.AsyncEx.1.0.0\lib\net40\Nito.AsyncEx.Enlightenment.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Core">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=2.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.1.10\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Extensions">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.1.10\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Primitives">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.1.10\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=2.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.1.10\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.0.19\lib\net40\System.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.1.0.19\lib\net40\System.Threading.Tasks.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Form1.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="TestBoxInstall_TemporaryKey.pfx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.4.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Windows Installer 4.5</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.10\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.10\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureBclBuildImported" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(BclBuildImported)' == ''">
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.10\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567." HelpKeyword="BCLBUILD2001" />
    <Error Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.10\tools\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets')" Text="The build restored NuGet packages. Build the project again to include these packages in the build. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317568." HelpKeyword="BCLBUILD2002" />
  </Target>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on the specifics of the application? (ie. is it a console application, WPF, etc).  Also, how are you deploying the application? Does it fail during deployment or after it's deployed an error is thrown when trying to run the application. I'm not entirely sure where that error output is coming from, but is it possible that the machines require strong naming?

Comment: It's a Windows Form application.  For now, I'm copying the .exe and dll's to a virtual machine for testing. The error comes from a popup window when I try to launch the program.  I'm building on .net 4.0 in 6

Comment: I'm trying to build a 64-bit .Net application for Windows 7.  The errors I'm getting seem to suggest some issue with incompatibility between 32-bit and 64-bit libraries.

Comment: As for strong naming... I don't have any idea.

Comment: Any suggestions on where I should go from here?